# After the nameserver edits, the site can't be reached

Tags: domain-name-system, migration

I need urgent help as my hosting provider doesn't seem to have proper answers any time. I migrated my hosting plan from one server to a new local hosting provider server. First, I changed the A-records at the old host. Things worked good and I could see the new IP when I pinged my website on RUN window. Then, after 12 hours i.e yesterday, I edited the name servers.

But, Things just got horrible this morning. The website isn't working and when I pinged it showed the old hosting IP. After no concrete answer from new or old provider, I again updated the Nameservers. Its been 9 hours since I updated the nameserver.

Right now, When i ping, I see no IP. Even on http://www.whatsmydns.net/ and http://www.viewdns.info , nothing can be seen. In fact, viewdns website says **Sorry, I couldn't seem to find that domain. Perhaps you entered an invalid domain name? Please check the spelling and try again later.**

Why is this happening. Is there something I have done wrong ?

Why isn't any server around the world able to ping me. I understand that the complete propogation might take time, but atleast one server around the world should be able to show any result. Please check my website **eyaas.com** yourself by pinging or on the dns checker website.

Please Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Root zone records show `n3.znet.in` and `ns4.znet.in` are the two listed nameservers for `eyaas.com`. However, neither of them seem to be offering name service for this domain.

Comment: yes these nameservers were given by my new host. How can they not offer name service for my domain ? :-O :-( . What should I do in this regard

Comment: Most likely the [glue records](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System#Circular_dependencies_and_glue_records) for your domain were not updated to resolve to your new nameservers. Contact your domain registrar/reseller. They should be able to help you with the issue.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers , I contacted my domain registrar 9 hours ago only. They said that your nameservers are already updated and set as provided by your new hosting provider. BTW, do you think the problem will get solved by itself. My new hosting provider said wait 24 hours atleast but I am bit skeptical that something is wrong at my end

Comment: Without knowing how it's supposed to work, there's no way I can answer those questions. What are the name servers supposed to be? And what are you supposed to be waiting for? (The root zone to be updated? Your host's nameservers to be updated?)

Comment: I transfered my website from one host to another and i updated the Nameservers 10 hours ago. The nameservers are supposed to be what you referred in the answer i.e **ns3.znet.in and ns4.znet.in**. I am waiting for the website to show up. Still, when i ping or use any dns tool, I don't see it pointing to any ip.

Comment: Your domain registrar did their job. `ns3.znet.in` and `ns4.znet.in` are your listed nameservers and the root nameservers for `.com` are redirecting people there. The problem is that neither of those nameservers is serving your domain. The problem is with your hosting provider -- they have no setup those nameservers yet. Ideally, they would have set them up before you switched to them with your registrar as that avoids this downtime.

Comment: Ok. But, then why they say I should wait for 24-72 hours for domain propagation. BTW, before updating the nameservers, I edited the A-records on old servers with new server's IP. Things worked well then :-/

Comment: @PankajUpadhyay: What did they tell you that you were supposed to be waiting for? If it's something that hasn't happened yet, then that may be fine. If it's something that already happened, and it's still not working, then you have a problem. "Domain propagation" is gobbledygook. Domains don't need to propagate. Your issue right now is that `ns3.znet.in` and `ns4.znet.in` are not serving your domain.

Comment: Ohh k. So, in short, their nameservers have not been set to serve my domain(which i suppose doesn't take much time, right ??) and they are just making me a fool saying that downtime of 24-72 hours will be there for domain propogation.

Comment: Well, it might take them a lot of time depending on what their internal procedures are like. But there's no good reason it should have to take a lot of time. Nothing has to propagate anywhere, except perhaps from their database to their server or whatever strange internal process they have. Nothing has to propagate into or out of their systems -- it's all internal to them.

Comment: Thanks mate for your patience and response. Still, when i chatted with those people, they had to say the same thing. The domain propagation will take 24-72 hours and asked me to wait :(

Comment: It sounds like they will make you wait while either their server people get around to fixing the configuration or they escalate and someone figures out that nobody bothered to do it. That sounds like poor customer service to me, since "domain propagation" has already taken place and they clearly are unable to check that and are just following a script.

Comment: It is working now.